# Sequelize/Postgres: NUMERIC scale 7 must be between 0 and precision 2

Tags: javascript, postgresql, heroku, sequelize.js, heroku-postgres

**Issue**
Can't seem to figure out how to resolve error when migrating decimal to Heroku.

In my sequelize, it is running fine but heroku is giving me this error for postgres:

**migration**

```
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Spots', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      address: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
        allowNull: false
      },
      city: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false
      },
      state: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false
      },
      country: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false
      },
      lat: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10, 7)
      },
      lng: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10, 7)
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50)
      },
      description: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(255)
      },
      price: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(4, 2)
      },
      avgStarRating: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(2, 1)
      },
      ownerId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
      }
    });
  },
```

**Error**

```
ERROR: NUMERIC scale 7 must be between 0 and precision 2
```

**Sample output:**

```
{
  "Spots": [
    {
      ...,
      "lat": 37.7645358,
      "lng": -122.4730327,
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Have tried changing all the DECIMAL to NUMERIC/FLOAT (just to try if it work) and still resulted in same error. What may I be doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a numeric type, the first number is the **total** number of digits to be represented, including both sides of the decimal point. The second value is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point. Thus, `(2, 7)` does not make sense.

Comment: I see. If I am understanding it correctly, if I want to get 9 digits in total (2 numbers in front and 7 numbers in the back), I changed it to (9, 7). Its still giving me the same error. For example, lat is "37.7645358" in decimal form.

Comment: It's giving you *exactly* the same error?

Comment: Yes, after pushing to the master branch and running "heroku run npm run sequelize db:migrate". Got the same error again

Comment: Also latitude values can have three significant digits to the left of the decimal point, and that amount of fractional precision is probably not worth it because it's almost impossible that it's accurate.

Comment: If you got the exact same error then you did not successfully deploy it. 9 is a different number than 2.

Comment: Wow.. thank you for your help, Pointy. I did not push it to heroku, it ran successfully now